# how to compute multivariable derivative of order 2?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{y^4}{x^2+y^2}\text{ if } (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\
0\hspace{1.4cm}\text{ if } (x,y)=(0,0).\end{cases}$$
I can compute $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)}{x-0}.$
How can I calculate $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(0,0)$?

Comment: Compute not only $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ but also $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$ for $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$.  Then use your limit method on that.

Comment: I still don't know how to calculate derivative of order 2 at a point. Can you do an example?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. So the second derivative is equal to $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,0)-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}({\textbf{0}})}{x-0} $$
Hence you need both $f_y(x,y),(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ to compute the second derivative.

In this case, you get $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\begin{cases}\dfrac{2y^3(2x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}&\text{ if $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$}\\[5pt]
0&\text{if $(x,y)=(0,0)$}
\end{cases}$$
So the required derivative is obviously $0$.